# Not understanding a step in proving $P\leftrightarrow Q = (P\wedge Q)\vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm struggling to see a transition step in proving that: $P\leftrightarrow Q = (P\wedge Q)\vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$.  Starting with the former:

1. $\neg(P\wedge \neg Q) \wedge \neg(Q \wedge \neg P)$ (Conditional laws)
2. $(\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P)$ (Demorgan's)
3. $((\neg P \vee Q) \wedge \neg Q) \vee ((\neg P \vee Q) \wedge P)$ (Distributive)
4. $(\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (Q \wedge P)$ **This is the step I don't understand, stepping from 3 to 4**
5. $(P \wedge Q)\vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ (Commutative)

As in the list of steps, the step from 3 from 4 is opaque to me.  I don't understand the gymnastics that the solution steps through to get there.

Because the $(\neg P \vee Q)$ is nested in those paranthesis and the fact that there is a different operation, they cannot use associativity to trivially move the parenthesis around.

Comment: By distribution, $(\lnot P\lor Q)\land \lnot Q = (\lnot P\land \lnot Q)\lor (Q\land \lnot Q)$. Note that $Q\land \lnot Q$ is always false, so this is equivalent to $\lnot P\land \lnot Q$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you distribute once more you get
$$ (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q\land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land P) \lor (Q\land P) $$
Then just remove the contradictions.